# Spring Framework name background

Tags: java, spring

What does spring mean in reference to Spring Framework? I don't think that this just the favorite season of its author)

Comment: I hope Rod Johnson is lurking here, because I doubt that anyone else knows what was going through his mind when he switched the name from Interface21 to Spring.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may get the history [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2006/11/08/spring-framework-the-origins-of-a-project-and-a-name/).

> Fortunately Yann stepped up with a
>   suggestion: "Spring". His reasoning
>   was association with nature (having
>   noticed that I’d trekked to Everest
>   Base Camp in 2000); and the fact that
>   **Spring represented a fresh start after
>   the "winter" of traditional J2EE**.

Answer (score 0):

Below paragraph from Rod Johnson [creator of spring framework] blog tells the history behind spring framework name.

Whatever happened next, the framework needed a name. In the book it was referred to as the “Interface21 framework” (at that point it used com.interface21 package names), but that was not a name to inspire a community. Fortunately Yann stepped up with a suggestion: “Spring”. His reasoning was association with nature (having noticed that I'd trekked to Everest Base Camp in 2000); and the fact that Spring represented a fresh start after the “winter” of traditional J2EE. We recognized the simplicity and elegance of this name, and quickly agreed on it.

The detail story behind naming framework as spring is here 
https://spring.io/blog/2006/11/09/spring-framework-the-origins-of-a-project-and-a-name

Comment: This question already had an accepted answer. How does your answer improve upon the already accepted one?  In fact, it looks like you just plagiarized from it?